# Dynamic table which contains multiple submit forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am developing a shopping cart website in MVC3 with razor. Below code is view code, in which I am showing multiple products, each product has quantity text box and one submit button. So, in controller how would I know which submit button is called by user and how to read text from Label?

```
    <table>
    <tr>

   @foreach (System.Data.DataRow i in Model.dt.Rows ) 
  {
      using (@Html.BeginForm("addtocart", "Chocolatier",FormMethod.Post,null))
       {
       <tr><td>  <img src=" @Url.Content("~/Content/abc.gif") "  alt="Imge" height ="40" width ="40"/></td></tr>
          foreach (System.Data.DataColumn j in Model.dt.Columns)
          {
              lbl = "lbl";
              lbl = lbl+@cnt.ToString();
              if(j.ToString().ToLower ().Equals ("name"))
              {
                 <tr> <td style="width : 200px"><h5>@j.ToString()</h5><label id="@lbl" >@i[j].ToString()</label></td></tr>

              }
              if(j.ToString().ToLower ().Equals ("description"))
              {
                 <tr> <td style="width : 200px"><h5>@j.ToString()</h5>@i[j].ToString())</td></tr>
              }
              if(j.ToString().ToLower ().Equals ("price"))
              {
                  <tr> <td style="width : 200px"><h5>@j.ToString()</h5>@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.prod_price,i[j].ToString())</td></tr>
              }

          }
                cnt += 1;
           <td>Enter quantity :&nbsp;@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.prod_quantity)</td>      
     <tr><td><input type ="submit" value="Add to cart" id="@cnt"/></td></tr>

       <tr>     <td>__________________________________________________________________________</td></tr>

     }                

    }
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why are you not using a model fields to enter the data? something like `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity)` instead of the input

Comment: Guillelon can you tell me..how to read Label value in controller class.

Comment: You´re passing the view a Model right? And then fill that model in the view and return it again to the Controllers action Post Method. I'll recommend you this tutorial, sou you can learn the basis about MVC -> http://tinyurl.com/72e6e2y read it and let me know ;)